# How do I create a Map of int and list?

Tags: flutter, dart

I feel like I missed something, as this question seems so easy to answer. However, I haven't found anything on stack overflow or in the dart docs.

What I've tried:

```
var list = Map<int, List<int>>();

list[0] = [];
```

or

```
var list = Map<int, List<int>>();

list[0] = List<int> listOne;
```

The docs didn't help much:
https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#maps

And a similar question doesn't seem to exist.

How can I solve this problem. Do I need to use a workaround?

Greetings.

Answer (score 2):

**Map of int and list**

```
var listMapping = Map<int, List<int>>();    
listMapping[0] = [];
listMapping[33] = [12, 0, 345, -23, 999999];
listMapping[45] = List<int>();

listMapping[45].add(101);
listMapping[45].add(109);

print(listMapping[33]);

// A map doesn't store things in a asequencial data structure e.g. List or array
// Hence it doesn't implement Iterable and hence it can not be traversed like below
/*for(List<int> list in listMapping){
   print(list);
}*/
```

**List of List**

If the integer key in your case is just to store the index and will always be sequencial e.g. 0,1,2,3... then a better solution would be a `List` of a `Lists`

```
var myLists = List<List<int>>()
myLists.add([1,2,45,56,78]);

var aNewList = [22,33,44,55];
myLists.add(aNewList);
```

Answer (score 2):

#### The first one looked fine

Im not sure if I am understanding you correctly, but your first attempt worked for me in the DartPad. I only renamed it to map, as it is a map which contains lists.

```
var map = Map<int, List<int>>();

map[0] = [];
```

You could also declare it as a final, as the variable itself doesn't get reassigned

```
final map = Map<int, List<int>>();
map[0] = [];
```

Give it a type annotation, if it helps you

```
final Map<int,List<int>> map = Map<int, List<int>>();

map[0] = [];
```

#### The second code snippet does not work

```
var list = Map<int, List<int>>();

//you cannot name a value you want to assign
list[0] = List<int> listOne;
```

Maybe this is what you were going for:

```
var list = Map<int, List<int>>();
final listOne = <int>[];
list[0] = listOne
```

#### Map literals

This is the way I would do it

```
final map = {0: []};
//or for added clarity 
final Map<int,List<int>> map = <int,List<int>>{0: []};
```

Simple operations with the map and its keys (int) and values (List)

```
//assign new array to different keys
map[0] = [0,1,2,3,4];
map[2] = <int>[];
map[4] = <int>[0,3];

//remove all values with an array length smaller than two
map.removeWhere((key,value)=>value.length<2);

//remove value at key 0
map.remove(0);

//clear map
map.clear();
```

**[NOTE]** If you want to reassign a completely new map to map, you would have to declare it non final

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<int, List<int>> map = Map<int, List<int>> ();
  map[0] = [10,0];
  map[1] = [];
```

[Learn more about dart maps](https://medium.com/@harshitp108/how-to-use-map-in-flutter-dart-21042334f537)